# Jquery's ThickBox: opening an iframe with GET parameters

Tags: jquery, get, thickbox

I tried all sorts of combinations, how can I open a page in thickbox that has get parameters in it? for example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?q=someQuery&TB_iframe=true&height=600&width=600" title"bla" class="thickbox">example 1</a?
```

Also, are there any special things to consider while working with thickbox in a firefox extension?

Answer (score 1):

BTW if you look at the documentation additional values should be before the thickbox parameters, e.g.

```
?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=400&width=600
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source of thickbox. Does the selector in the very begining match your links, something like

```
tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');
```

The following example works fine for me:

```
<a class="thickbox" href="/a/b/c/?id=42&TB_iframe=true&width=800">link</a>
```

Comment: this link opens an iframe from this href: a/b/c/?id=42&

Apparently this is the correct form:
href="http://www.google.com/search?q=helloTB_iframe=true&width=800"